# trino connector to flat files

Tags: flat-file, trino, query-engine

I am trying to create trino connector to query the data available in a flat file (say a text file with 100 records, each record is separated by newline and each column separated by comma). Trino documentation page (https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/localfile.html) shows how to create a connector for LocalFile but it works only for HTTP logs. Can any one help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As you already mentioned, it's only for HTTP logs and columns are [hard-coded](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/blob/master/plugin/trino-local-file/src/main/java/io/trino/plugin/localfile/LocalFileTables.java#LL117C9-L129C82):

```
private static final List<ColumnMetadata> COLUMNS = ImmutableList.of(
                SERVER_ADDRESS_COLUMN,
                new ColumnMetadata("timestamp", createTimestampWithTimeZoneType(3)),
                new ColumnMetadata("client_address", createUnboundedVarcharType()),
                new ColumnMetadata("method", createUnboundedVarcharType()),
                new ColumnMetadata("request_uri", createUnboundedVarcharType()),
                new ColumnMetadata("user", createUnboundedVarcharType()),
                new ColumnMetadata("agent", createUnboundedVarcharType()),
                new ColumnMetadata("response_code", BIGINT),
                new ColumnMetadata("request_size", BIGINT),
                new ColumnMetadata("response_size", BIGINT),
                new ColumnMetadata("time_to_last_byte", BIGINT),
                new ColumnMetadata("trace_token", createUnboundedVarcharType()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a workaround to on-board flat files? May be something like create a java code (like the one you have highlighted) and build trino from source?

Comment: An alternative is service provider interface. You can create a basic custom connector which reads data from a local file and either define columns dynamically, or you can use hard-coded columns if you have specific use cases and want to implement something with less effort. 

Tip 1: You can copy local file connector and adjust your use case and configure with custom name.
Tip 2: If you do not know how to do those stuff, I lately tried OpenAI and it generated working example.